# Python - inherited class method to operate on class attribute

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm sure there's probably a simple solution but anyway the problem is this: I've got two classes, say `A` and `B`, both of which have attributes that are dataframe like -- those attributes are instances of a dataframe class, call it `C`, which has its own methods. I'd like to define an 'interface like' class `D` which has methods that can operate on those attributes (i.e. operate on the dataframes which are attributes of `A` and `B`).

*edit for clarity*: in what follows below, let `a` and `b` be dataframes (i.e. instances) from class `C`. So that the methods of `C` are available to `a` and `b`.

To be more explicit: Suppose `a` is the dataframe like attribute of `A`, with attributes `Series1`,...,`Seriesn`. Since `a` is dataframe like, I can call 
`a.Series1, a.Series2, ...` etc to access the contents of `Series1`, `Series2` in `a`. Of course `a` is an attribute of `A` so I'm actually calling `A.a.Series1`, `A.a.Series2`.. etc, and `a` has its own methods from class `C` so I can call `A.a.Series1.methodfromclassC()` no problem. Anyhow. Now suppose I want to make a transformation in a consistent fashion to the contents of `a.Seriesj`, or `b.Seriesj`, implemented as a method in class `D`, that both `A` and `B` can access. The idea being that I'd like to be able to call a member of class `A` like so: `A.a.Seriesj.transformseries()`. The problem I run into is that `Seriesj` has its own methods (inherited from class `C`) and `transformseries()` is not one of them.

This probably seems a bit convoluted but the idea being that eventually I can chain multiple calls to the various methods of `D` changing the state of the dataframe attributes: `A.a.Series2.transform1().transform2().transformj()` or `B.b.Seriesj.transform6().transform3()` 
etc, so that the final representation of `A.a` and `B.b` is in the form that I'd like.

Comment: The explanation it's not clear to me. About the last sentences I think it's enough to return `self` to obtain that kind of thing.

Comment: You lose me here: If `a` inherits from `C` it doesn't necessarily follow that `a.Series1` inherits from `C` as well. Did you think it should, or is part of the explanation missing?

Comment: kojiro: Sorry for the ambiguity, yes `a` inherits from C and `a.Series1` inherits from C as well. I'll edit the post for clarity. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how this is OOP? It seems like AOP to me.

Comment: kojiro: I didn't really think it was controversial to include the oo tag for the post, since my question deals with objects, classes, etc. I'm not familiar with AOP so I'll look into it.

Comment: Not sure this helps, but are you using Pandas?

Comment: Alexandre: yes, but the transformations I'd like to accomplish with transformseries() won't rely solely on the methods available to pandas series/dataframes, which is why I avoided referencing it explicitly.

Comment: shouldn't it be `A.a.methodfromclassC()`?

Comment: @optional It's not controversial, but I thought maybe you didn't realize it was more AOP than OOP, and that it would help to know that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered "injecting" new methods to your `Seriesn`? In Python you can add methods to classes dynamically like this:

```
setattr(MyClass, 'new_method', lambda self: 'return value')
```

It will work even in objects instanced before. So you could add custom methods to Pandas' `Series` and/or `Dataframe` classes.